# Linux 2.3.36 Device-Filesystem omitted

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I read in a book that the Device-Filesystem should be omitted in the future.

Is that the case in Kernel 2.3.36 ?

Answer (score 1):

This is definitly not the case with 2.3.36, and I suspect it won't be the case in the foreseeable future: While the kernel itself might no longer be dependant on `/dev`, a close to infinite set of software in userland is. I really doubt mass-breaking software is a goal of kernel development.

Comment: @ Eugen: But in this case `devs_mk_cdev(MKDEV(MAJOR_NR,minor),S_IFCHR|S_IRUGO|S_IWUGO,"XXX");` should create a Device File with the name XXX. Right? But it doesn't.

Comment: You will find excellent documentation of the relevant APIs via kernel.org (or Google). If you can do `ls /dev` (and see e.g. your tty), you can be sure, that there is a device file system.

Comment: As a matter of fact: `devs_mk_cdev(..)` is a typo. You want `devfs_mk_cdev(..)`

Comment: I can see something. And thanks for the typo. But anyway, I can't find a declaration of devfs_mk_cdev(...) in my the whole linux sources